# Does LoopBack support SSE (Server-Sent Events)?

Tags: server, server-sent-events, loopbackjs, strongloop

I looked at the StrongLoop documentation and modules, but couldn't find anything except websocket support.

I was wondering if anyone has made an implementation of it yet, how did it go ? How is it doing? And if it's something that the StrongLoop team is planning on adding soon.

W3C Spec for SSE: http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-eventsource-20090423/

Comment: As far as I know there is no specific SSE implementation yet. But curious if anyone has tried it on their own as well...

Comment: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Realtime-server-sent-events.html#creating-changestreams-on-the-server